# Is there any way in iOS to find the exact time when we are connected to any device?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

If in our app we are acting as a `peripheral mode`. Don't we have anyway to find when we are connected to any device. I want to log the the time when my device connects to another device.
As in `central mode` we have this `CBPeripheralState` for getting the current state of the peripheral connected to us. But I could not find anything like `CBPeripheralState` as a `peripheral`.

Comment: I don't believe `CBPeripheralState` is really what you mean here. What you're looking for is a peripheral version of `centralManager(_:didConnect:)`. But I don't believe there is such a method (which I agree is somewhat surprising). The closest I know of are the `peripheralManager(_:did...)` methods to check the first time you're read/written/subscribed to.

Comment: I mean if you are acting as centralManager, you have CBPeripheralState for checking the state of the available peripheral like is it connected, connecting ... , My case is for Peripheral, and i didn't find any thing like that so can log the time for my peripheral as it connects to some device.

Comment: Yes; but I don't believe there's any equivalent when you're a peripheral. The closest you can do is note the first time a central asks to access an attribute.

Comment: This is the result I have in my mind till yet.